# Durandal 2.0.1, load all files initially

Tags: c#, javascript, html, durandal

I am using Durandal 2.0.1 there I am having a log-in page, and after successful log-in, a splash screen comes with a loading bar and download all the required files for SPA.

I trying to modify its behavior in such a way that, I am trying to download all the required files at the log-in page and get rid of the splash screen.

I am able to download the files at the log-in page but not able to get rid of the splash screen, because as soon as I remove the splash screen the SPA doesn't gets loaded.

Any suggestion or solution is welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While by default most Durandal examples come with a splash screen, adding a splash screen is optional.

#### index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="applicationHost">
        <div class="splash">
          <div class="message">
              Durandal Starter Project
          </div>
          <i class="icon-spinner icon-2x icon-spin active"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="app/main"></script>
</body>
```

Getting rid of the splash screen can be accomplished by removing `div.splash`. Make sure not to accidentally remove `#applicationHost` as that container is required by Durandal. See http://dfiddle.github.io/dStream/#search/applicationHost for me info.

```
<body>
    <div id="applicationHost">
       <!-- Whatever is in here will be overwritten when Durandal has finished loading -->
    </div>

    <script src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="app/main"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do some prefetching.

If that's the case, you should monitor the status of the [prefetch link relation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ).  In the meantime, you can use something like [PreloadJS](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS).  If you want to know how these kinds of prefetchers work (or want to implement something yourself), check out [this article](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) for a few pointers.

- [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102625/preload-script-without-execute) regarding AMD modules with RequireJS specifically.

PS Something bugs me in your question though;  you seem to imply that the behavior you want works as long as the splash screen is used.  Do you monitor the network to verify this? Also, you might want to quickly describe what kind of data you want to prefetch exactly.